# Why were the Isles of the Blest ruled over by Cronos and Rhea?

Tags: greek, afterlife

As I was researching Isles of the Blest, I came across something very confusing. According to [Maicar](http://www.maicar.com/GML/IslesBlest.html)...

> Rather, after three lifetimes, the souls of the good are conveyed to the Island of the Blest, ruled by Cronos and Rhea:
>
> "With these wreaths and garlands of flowers they entwine their hands according to the righteous counsels of Rhadamanthys, whom the great father, the husband of Rhea whose throne is above all others, keeps close beside him as his partner."

It wouldn't make sense for the Titan lord who tried to destroy the gods to rule over

> ...an easy existence:
>
> "But having the sun always in equal nights and equal days, the good receive a life free from toil, not scraping with the strength of their arms the earth, nor the water of the sea, for the sake of a poor sustenance. But in the presence of the honored gods, those who gladly kept their oaths enjoy a life without tears, while the others undergo a toil that is unbearable to look at."

Can someone explain why Cronos would rule over that place? He's dead right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cronos isn't dead; he's imprisoned. Later ([Theoi describes it](http://www.theoi.com/Titan/TitanKronos.html) as "Many human generations later"), Zeus frees Cronos.

[The very webpage you link to explains it](http://www.maicar.com/GML/IslesBlest.html) (by quoting from Hesiod's works and days):

> > And they live untouched by sorrow in the islands of the blessed along the shore of deep-swirling Ocean, happy heroes for whom the grain-giving earth bears honey-sweet fruit flourishing thrice a year, far from the deathless gods, and Cronos rules over them; **for the father of men and gods released him from his bonds.**

Of course, it's important to realize that not every account by ancient authors describes Cronos being set free, but enough do that we now include the story in our modern portrayal of Cronos.